# A simple question from a C beginner, about arrays

Tags: c, arrays, eof

I'm new to C language and I'm trying to make a program that includes an array of type int with the max length of 10.
I want to enter a random number of 1-digit numbers and set all the other values to 0.
For example, the console will look like this:

Enter B Values : 1 2 5 7 8

and the B array will look like this 1 2 5 7 8 0 0 0 0 0

I'm trying to add the numbers at the same line without using Enter.
Could anyone help?
Could the answer be EOF related?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to hit Enter just between the elements, or that you don't want to hit Enter even at the end?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Not really, I'm limited to the beginner's functions, such as scanf and EOF and array

Comment: Yes, I dont want to hit enter just between the elements and after I'm finished with filling, I have to press Enter only at the end

Comment: Not really, I'm limited to the basic way of reading input,  by scanf,

Comment: The input may not even reach your program before you hit `Enter`, it may be buffered in the terminal emulator. On Linux, you can use Ctrl+D to flush it, but note that flushing empty buffer will be treated as EOF.